# What permission do I need to build a rocket that goes to space?

Tags: rockets, karman-line

I wanted to build a rocket that goes to the karman line at 340000 feet which is technically space. I know the rules and what I need to get to launch the rocket such as faa clearance and more but I wanted to know if there were any certificates or permission I needed to build the rocket itself. I wanted to build one like the traveler 4 rocket as seen here http://www.uscrpl.com/traveler-iv this rocket reached the karman line with a solid rocket engine. I wanted to build something like this with a solid rocket engine. Hope someone can help thanks! EDIT: My location is in ohio, usa

Comment: You might want to include your location as the rules could vary widely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a level 3 certification for high power rocketry in order to get your hands on the stuff you need to build your rocket.  The industry has so far been self-regulating so this isn't an official requirement, but nobody will sell you the engines without it.

I suspect you also need a flight termination system on a rocket that goes that far as I seriously doubt you can ensure the rocket remains over property you have permission to fly over.  That's explosives which would require a blaster's license.

You're also in way beyond your depth, anyone who actually knows enough about rocketry to do this would not have asked the question.

Comment: Linking to reference citations would improve this Answer. For example, did you mean: https://www.nar.org/high-power-rocketry-info/level-3-certification/ ?

Comment: @BasilBourque Yeah--I didn't have the link at hand and since the important part was that he was way beyond his depth I didn't feel the need to hunt it down.

Comment: The links would be for the rest of us uninformed readers who are curious.